# Leaf pictures: Which disease?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I had several plants that with same symptoms, which all eventually died within some weeks: Formation of blisters along stem (no picture) and leaf veins, that seem to pop up (assumption) and make everything around sticky. The disease started with citrus plants (diverse limes) that I bought.

I thought it must be a some microorganism, but strangely close-up pictures resemble some flea-like morphology of the blisters, which makes me so curious that I ask this question. The plant leafs are Kaffir limes, approximately 6 cm long.

Also, would you have any idea how to save my plants?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I forgot to say, you can scrub them off with a toothbrush, but that won't kill the eggs. Needs to be repeated several times. Good luck!

Comment: Great, I will try that! 

Answer (score 7):

It looks like a scale insect to me, similar to [Citricola scale](https://cisr.ucr.edu/invasive-species/citricola-scale) but lighter in color. It might be a Soft Brown Scale, but they usually appear multiple generations at a time, so you'd see all sizes from tiny to full grown, whereas citricola scale usually appears as a single generation (all approximately the same size.) Either way, they suck the life out of plant leaves and will reduce their vigor and setting of fruit, while secreting a sweet liquid that promotes fungal growth.

When I see a scale insect, it gets scraped off the plant with my fingernail or a knife (and smooshed), and the leaf gets cleaned. If the leaf has been injured, I either get rid of it or rub a tiny bit of a mixture of beeswax and olive oil on the spot. Clearly this won't work for you. As I don't use any insecticides (unless you count my fingernails, etc.), I can't give you any advice about control, but it should be easy to search online.

[image]

Photograph from the United States National Collection of Scale Insects Photographs

Comment: It is only necessary to scrape them off with a nail ; they will not reattach.

Comment: That's true, but I don't like plant pests... If insects in my garden are unsightly but basically harmless, I leave them alone. If they are harmful, they are no more.